# There is a mistake in graph equation

Tags: excel

I have 6 to 6 values and I used them for graph. However, after I wrote the equation in a cell, it takes impossible values. The value should be close to 8604 , but it is -2678,39.

R^2=1

Equation: y= 5E-09x^5-7E-06x^4+0,0033x^3-0,6587x^2+42,543x+13892

Comment: What is `x`in your equation when `y` should be "near to 8604"? And what is `0'6587`?

Comment: İt should be 0,6587 , x is 569

Comment: In your equation y will be near to 8604 if x is either -57.22432623 or 402.140508 or 688.613155299887.